# Type of any in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

I've recently started trying to learn Haskell by reading LearnYouAHaskell and random articles from the internet.

I'm having hard time understanding more sophisticated function types.

Some examples that I understand.

```
> :t map  
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It takes in a function (which takes a and gives out b, i.e a and b can be of different types) and a list of a's and return a list of b's.

```
> :t fst  
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

Takes in a tuple of 2 elements (allows different types) and returns the first one.

```
> :t any
```

At a higher level, I understand `any`. It takes in a function and a list and returns true if any of the list entries return true for that particular function. I've used it in Python and JavaScript as well.

**Questions**

- I don't understand how does `any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`
   translate to the above.

  - `(a -> Bool)` is the predicate. Takes in an argument and returns true or false.
  - `t a -> Bool` Bool is the end result of any. According to my understanding t and a represent the predicate and the list. Why aren't they separated by a `->`
- How to go about understanding type signatures in general and how to dig deeper so that I can approach them myself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

Here `Foldable t` means, that `t` is an instance of type class `Foldable`.

`Foldable` is a type class and if type `t` is an instance of the type class `Foldable` we know from the `t a` part of the signature or from the definition of the type class `Foldable`, that `t` is actually a type constructor.

So `t a` is a type and therefore `t a -> Bool` is a function, that maps a value of type `t a` to `Bool`. This function will be closure, which will
apply the predicate to each "element" of the value of type `t a`, until it finds one, that yields `True` under the predicate or it doesn't find such an element returning either `True` or `False` in the respective cases. (The actual implementation might be very different.)

For example `[]` is an instance of the type class `Foldable` and therefore `t a` could be a list of something. In this case, we can also write `[a]` instead of `[] a`.

But there are other type constructors, which can be instances of `Foldable`, for example some kinds of trees.

Comment: Thanks. Aren't type classes enclosed like `(Eq a)`?

Comment: If there is only one typeclass, one can omit the paran.. parenth.. the `()` thingies in the function signature.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `[a]` is just a special form for the application of the type constructor `[]` to the type variable `a`, which makes replacing the literal value `[]` with the variable `t` more understandable.

Answer (score 10):

It might be helpful to note that [until recently, the signature was actually](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any)

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

This was generalised during [the Foldable Traversable in Prelude proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude): now the container of values need not be a list, but can as well be e.g. an [array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#t:Vector):

```
Prelude> import qualified Data.Vector as Arr
Prelude Arr> :set -XOverloadedLists
Prelude Arr> let a = [1,2,3] :: Arr.Vector Int
Prelude Arr> any (>2) a
True
```

Comment: The first signature is so readable. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Type signature is a mark up designation of the function indicating the  types to be processed and how the function can be partially applied.

```
Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

By `Foldable t` it first says `any` function can work with any data type which is an instance of Foldable type class.

The first parameter, `(a -> Bool)` is obviously a function which takes a single element (`a`) from our foldable data type and returns a `Bool` type value. It's the the callback of `.some(callback)` in JavaScript. When you apply this parameter to `any` you will be returned with a function of type;

`t a -> Bool`

Now we are left with a single function which takes only one parameter and returns a `Bool` type (`True` or `False`) value. Again `t a` is a data type which is a member of the Foldable type class. It can be a `[]` but a `Tree` too provided that the data type has `foldMap` function defined under an instance to Foldable. It's the `myArr` part in JavaScript's `myArr.some(callback)` except that it doesn't have to be an array.

Comment: Makes sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

`t a` isn't separated by a `->` because the `t a` is the instance of foldable, ex: List a, or Tree a.  Let's go back to `map` for a second. The version you gave is specialized to lists; a more general version (which, as an accident of history, is called `fmap` in most versions of Haskell) has type `fmap :: Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b`.  Where is your input list in this signature?  It's the `f a`.  Now, returning to `any` the `t a` is the second argument, the instance of Foldable you're folding over, the list or tree or whatever.

You'll read that all functions in Haskell really have only 1 argument, and we're seeing that here. `any` takes it's first argument (the predicate) and returns a  function that takes a foldable (the list, tree, etc) and returns a `Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`t a` does not represent the predicate and the list. As you've already correctly pointed out before, `(a -> Bool)` is the predicate. `t a` just represents the list, except it doesn't have to be a list (that's why it's `t a` instead of `[a]`). `t` can be any Foldable, so it could be `[]`, but it could also be some other collection type or `Maybe`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks